# C++ - Map of pairs - check if a pair with given first coordinate exists

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++14

I'm holding a map sorted on `std::pair<K, V>`. (It's type is `std::map<std::pair<K, V>, size_t>`). I want to find ANY pair with given first coordinate (i.e. with `K` fixed, find if there is any object in map, with key of form `std::pair<K, _>`, I don't care about the second coordinate). Obviously it can be done in O(log n), as searching specific pair is also done in O(log n) [that's standard find() operation]. Is there some way to do that without having to write my own map from scratch?

One more thing - I can't change comparing function, as I want pairs like `(1,2), (1,3)` to be different, and if comparator compares keys only, it will treat them as equals. I want to preserve standard find() operation, as I need to use it as well.

The solution from [Finding any element with specific first coordinate in `set<pair> >`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577818/finding-any-element-with-specific-first-coordinate-in-setpair) will not work as I have only guarantee that `operator <` is provided for both `K` and `V`.  I do not know if `std::numeric_limits` is specialized for `K`

Comment: Generic types (it's template class)

Comment: I have only guarantee that operator < is provided for both K and V

Comment: If you allowed C++14, you might get more interesting answers involving is_transparent.

Comment: I voted to reopen your question as you said you do not know if you can get a minimum value.  I also edit your question to explain that.  Feel free to edit if you do not like it.

Comment: You can replace the numeric_limits value with any value for V (copy it from the first element for instance). Then you need to check both the output of lower_bound and the previous element, but the idea still works.

Answer (score 2):

If you need *any* value with key equal to `x`, use a dummy value for `V`. If it's default-constructible, you can just put `V()` as the second, dummy element of the key; else pick the value from the map (e.g. from the first element). Then search for `lower_bound` with that key and also look at the previous element:

```
auto it = my_container.lower_bound(std::make_pair(x, V()));
bool found;
if (it == my_container.end()) {
    found = false;
} else {
    found = it->first.first == x;
    if (!found && it != my_container.begin()) {
        it--;
        found = it->first.first == x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest breaking up the map into two maps:

```
multimap<K, map<V, size_t>>
```

And performing the pair construction/deconstruction using make_pair and get.

Also consider using unordered_multimap/unordered_map for the outer/inner maps if you don't need the order preserved.